# how can I retrieve documents from MarkLogic based upon their insertion time

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I am trying to figure out a way to retrieve documents from MarkLogic based upon time the documents were inserted.

For what i know is, using `xdmp:document-timestamp` to check the document timestamp, but this timestamp depends upon the recent updates to a document. SO does MarkLogic maintains the insertion timestamp of documents? and if yes then how can i use it?

Presently, i am using predicate in `fn:doc()[last()-10 to last()]` as an example to get the most recently inserted documents. But I want a more dynamic way to get document between a specific timestamp.

Answer (score 4):

MarkLogic has the option to automatically maintain last modified. It is an option from the earlier days, and saves a lastModified property in the properties-fragment. Properties are stored in a separate fragment however, causing extra overhead, and a bigger footprint on disk. If possible, consider adding a element or property to the document itself, and maintaining that yourself. You can do that in an ingest transform, or (if you want to be very sure it is always there) in a pre-commit trigger. Use the envelop-pattern if you want to keep the original content separate from these additions.

Once you have that element, you can put an ordinary range index on it, and use that for querying and sorting results. If you want latest 10 docs, make sure to sort descending, and then grab first 10.

If you would like to use the date for relevance scoring as well, make sure to use a non-zero score-function option with your range query. See also: http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-range-query

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

MarkLogic does not do that automatically (maybe for bi-temporal docs or DLS?).

Furthermore, you may not rely on URIs to be in order of insertion.

What you want sounds like part of the Content Processing Framework([CPF](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cpf.pdf)).  CPF stores some useful information in the Properties fragments. If this is not enough, there are samples of pipelines to keep things like inserted and updated timestamps, etc.

-Or through your own code or triggers store this information in the way that best suites your need. You don't have to use CPF for this and if it is your only use-case, CPF could be a bit overkill for some situations as it has overhead. A trigger or your own code can affect the same result. Where you store the data is up to you. If you are not already using properties and have a handy place in your document (some header section or a wrapper), then store it there rather than a property fragment (for a few reasons). Then again, if you have binary content, then using properties is the option.

Comment: Agreed, I think you'll need application-level code to insert an element with the timestamp you want to track.